MT5 Manager API: UserSubscribe Not Triggering OnUserLogin Event
I'm working with the MetaTrader 5 (MT5) Manager API to monitor user login events. I successfully subscribe to user events, but the OnUserLogin event handler is not being triggered when users log in.
Here is a simplified version of my implementation:
CManager.cs:
using MetaQuotes.MT5CommonAPI;
using MetaQuotes.MT5ManagerAPI;
using System;

namespace SimpleLoginApp
{
    public class CManager : IDisposable
    {
        uint MT5_CONNECT_TIMEOUT = 30000;
        CIMTManagerAPI m_manager = null;
        UserSink m_userSink = null;

        public CManager()
        {
            m_userSink = new UserSink();
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Shutdown();
        }

        public bool Initialize()
        {
            string message = string.Empty;
            MTRetCode res = MTRetCode.MT_RET_OK_NONE;

            if ((res = SMTManagerAPIFactory.Initialize(null)) != MTRetCode.MT_RET_OK)
            {
                message = string.Format("Loading manager API failed ({0})", res);
                Console.WriteLine(message);
                return false;
            }

            m_manager = SMTManagerAPIFactory.CreateManager(SMTManagerAPIFactory.ManagerAPIVersion, out res);
            if ((res != MTRetCode.MT_RET_OK) || (m_manager == null))
            {
                SMTManagerAPIFactory.Shutdown();
                message = string.Format("Creating manager interface failed ({0})", (res == MTRetCode.MT_RET_OK ? "Managed API is null" : res.ToString()));
                Console.WriteLine(message);
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }

        public bool Login(string server, UInt64 login, string password)
        {
            MTRetCode res = m_manager.Connect(server, login, password, null, CIMTManagerAPI.EnPumpModes.PUMP_MODE_USERS, MT5_CONNECT_TIMEOUT);
            if (res != MTRetCode.MT_RET_OK)
            {
                m_manager.LoggerOut(EnMTLogCode.MTLogErr, "Connection failed ({0})", res);
                Console.WriteLine($"Connection failed ({res})");
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }

        public void Logout()
        {
            if (m_manager != null)
                m_manager.Disconnect();
        }

        public void Shutdown()
        {
            if (m_manager != null)
            {
                m_manager.Dispose();
                m_manager = null;
            }

            SMTManagerAPIFactory.Shutdown();
        }

        public bool SubscribeToUserEvents()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("subscribing");
            Console.WriteLine("m_manager: " + m_manager);
            Console.WriteLine("m_userSink: " + m_userSink);
            if (m_manager != null && m_userSink != null)
            {
                MTRetCode res = m_manager.UserSubscribe(m_userSink);
                if (res != MTRetCode.MT_RET_OK)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Failed to subscribe to user events: {res}");
                }
                return res == MTRetCode.MT_RET_OK;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }

    public class UserSink : CIMTUserSink
    {
        public UserSink()
        {
            RegisterSink();
        }

        public override void OnUserLogin(string ip, CIMTUser user, CIMTUser.EnUsersConnectionTypes type)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("OnUserLogin event triggered.");
            if (user != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"User Login - IP: {ip}, User: {user.Name()}, Login: {user.Login()}, Type: {type}");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("OnUserLogin event triggered, but user is null.");
            }
        }
 
    }
}

Program.cs:
using MetaQuotes.MT5CommonAPI;
using MetaQuotes.MT5ManagerAPI;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SimpleLoginApp
{
    class Program
    {
        public static CManager manager = new CManager();

        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var server = server_;
            var login = login_;
            var password = pass_; 

            try
            {
                using (manager)
                {
                    if (!manager.Initialize())
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Initialization failed.");
                        return;
                    }

                    if (!manager.Login(server, login, password))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Login failed.");
                        return;
                    }

                    Console.WriteLine("Successfully logged in to the manager API.");

                    if (manager.SubscribeToUserEvents())
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Successfully subscribed to user events.");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Failed to subscribe to user events.");
                    }

                    // Keep the application running to receive events
                    Console.WriteLine("Waiting for user login events...");
                    await Task.Delay(-1);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("log.txt", true))
                {
                    writer.WriteLine($"Exception: {ex.ToString()}");
                    writer.WriteLine("-----------");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Issue:
The application prints "Successfully subscribed to user events," indicating the subscription is successful.
However, the OnUserLogin event handler is never triggered when users log in.
This is the printout of the app:
Successfully logged in to the manager API.
subscribing
m_manager: MetaQuotes.MT5ManagerAPI.CIMTManagerAPI
m_userSink: SimpleLoginApp.UserSink
Successfully subscribed to user events.

What I've Tried:
Verified that the SubscribeToUserEvents method returns MT_RET_OK.
Ensured the application runs continuously to catch login events.
Added debug statements to confirm the subscription and event handling setup.
Questions:
Are there any additional configurations or steps required to ensure the OnUserLogin event is triggered?
Is there a way to manually test or trigger user login events for debugging purposes?
Could there be an issue with the MetaTrader server configuration or the way events are handled?
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!


Since I don't have access to the Apis soni won't actually comment on what you have written in terms of code. But Have you checked the event pump mode you're using (PUMP_MODE_USERS) and that it supports user login events. Sometimes, using a different pump mode or an additional one might be necessary to receive all relevant events.

Also check if your account has the right permissions to get the data what you are using.


